# subclassing sorl-thumbnail `ThumbnailBackend` class, and overriding _get_thumbnail_filename does not work

Tags: django, inheritance, sorl-thumbnail, overriding

I intend to subclass the `ThumbnailBackend` class from `sorl.thumbnail.base`. What I need to do is to override the `_get_thumbnail_filename` method, to add some stuff to the filename generated by the original (parent) method. To do so, I wrote something like this:

```
from sorl.thumbnail.base import ThumbnailBackend

class MyThumbnailBackend(ThumbnailBackend):
    def _get_thumbnail_filename(self, source, geometry_string, options):
        oldpath = super(ThumbnailBackend,self)._get_thumbnail_filename(source, geometry_string, options)
        oldpathlist = oldpath.split('/')
        # get the last item of 'oldpathlist' and
        # sufix it with useful info...
        # join the items with the modified one...
        return newpath
```

There should be something I'm missing with python inheritance, because I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError at /location/of/the/caller/class/
'super' object has no attribute '_get_thumbnail_filename'
```

If I'm right, I'm importing [this class](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/sorl/thumbnail/base.py), in the first line: `from sorl.thumbnail.base import ThumbnailBackend` which definitely has a `_get_thumbnail_filename` method.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call super with the current class, change `super(ThumbnailBackend, self)` to `super(MyThumbnailBackend, self)`, like this

```
class MyThumbnailBackend(ThumbnailBackend):
    def _get_thumbnail_filename(self, source, geometry_string, options):
        return super(MyThumbnailBackend, self)._get_thumbnail_filename(source, geometry_string, options)
```